# wkhtmltopdf loading multiple pages fails

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I am using `WkHtmlToPDF` and this php library http://mikehaertl.github.com/phpwkhtmltopdf/ to generate a single pdf with many pages. The strange thing is that when I have 3 pages it loads instantaneously. If I load 4 pages it acts as though it's in an infinite loop. I am loading random orders from a database so that it's not repeating any orders to avoid it being an order that is crashing it. I loop through each order and call `addPage` then call `send()`

```
foreach($orders as $order_id)
{
    $order = $this->orders_model->get_order($order_id);
    if(!empty($order))
    {
        $this->wkhtmltopdf->addPage($this->template->build('invoice', array(
            'order' => $order
        ), true));
    }
}

$this->wkhtmltopdf->send();
```

I have tried removing memory limits, I have tried setting timeout to 0

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
```

That didn't change anything, same result. I also looked in the apache logs, php error logs and my application's logs and I cannot come to a conclusion as to why it would stop working as soon as I do 4 orders.

Comment: Have you tried piping `stderr` to a file to see what `wkhtmltopdf` is saying?

Comment: what do you mean by crashes? Do you have an error message?

Comment: @ColinMorelli I have not, let me try that and get back to you

Comment: @John sorry that is a very vague description. When I say crashes I mean't it acts as though it's in an infinite loop.

Comment: @ColinMorelli When I pipe `stderr` to a file, when generating 3 pages, It shows the progress and states done. When I do it with 4 pages it never gets to the point where it can pipe it to a file.

Comment: @brenjt So it's not in wkhtmltopdf, then. What does the `wkhtmltopdf` object do in your code?

Comment: @ColinMorelli It's sending a shell command to the `wkhtmltopdf` lib on the server. Here is the command: `wkhtmltopdf tmp/tmpD32B.tmp.html --disable-smart-shrinking --stop-slow-scripts tmp/tmpD33C.tmp.html --disable-smart-shrinking --stop-slow-scripts tmp/tmpD34D.tmp`

Comment: @ColinMorelli You are right it is not the wkhtmltopdf. It might be the headers being sent out for displaying. Investigating further

Comment: Also try setting --no-pdf-compression to true, it helped me in similar cases.

Comment: If you find this because you are trying to generate a multi-page PDF that corrupts, try the --no-pdf-compression that Wesam suggested. Doing so fixed my issue of printing a 9-13 page document.